# Insert comma after every 7th character using regex and hive sql

Tags: sql, regex, hive

Insert comma after every 7th character and make sure the data is having comma after every 7th character correctly using regex in hive sql.

Also to ignore the space while selecting the 7th character.

Sample Input Data:

```
12F123f, 123asfH 0DB68ZZ, AG12453
112312f, 1212sfH 0DB68ZZ, AQ13463
```

Output:

```
12F123f,123asfH,0DB68ZZ,AG12453
112312f,1212sfH,0DB68ZZ,AQ13463
```

I tried the below code, but it didn't work and insert the commas correctly.

```
select regexp_replace('12345 12456,12345 123', '(/(.{5})/g,"$1$")','')
```

Comment: Maybe `select regexp_replace('12345 12456,12345 123', '(.{5})', '$1,')`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry if i have not mentioned earlier, it should ignore space while selecting the 5th character. In your query it includes space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```
select regexp_replace('12345 12456,12345 123', '(?!^)[\\s,]+([^\\s,]+)', ',$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkYI4V/1)

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - no match if at string start
- `[\s,]+` - 1 or more whitespaces or commas
- `([^\s,]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than whitespaces and commas.

The `,$1` replacement replaces the match with a comma and the value in Group 1.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace the empty char to `,`, am I right? the SQL as below:

```
select regexp_replace('12F123f,123asfH 0DB68ZZ,AG12453',' ',',') as result;
+----------------------------------+--+
|              result              |
+----------------------------------+--+
| 12F123f,123asfH,0DB68ZZ,AG12453  |
+----------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: No, that was just a sample data. I want to insert comma after every 7th character. Ignore blank spaces while selecting the 7th character.

Comment: @bill_123, ok ,got it ,let me try.